# which is the best drive backup software

Tags: backup, backup-restoration

Iam using window 2008 server on drive C
and then on D drive i have all virtual machines folder.

I also have two more internal SATA drives

i want to backup the whole HD i.e drive C and D.

I like the way Vmware workstation takes snapshot of VM.

Is there any software or utility from where i can make snapshots or backups just like vmware so that i can restore at any time in the past.

The best thing which i like is that e,g i want test some software then first i make the snapshot of current state and then if something goes wrong i go back to that snapshot.

is there anything like that for actual OS  just like vmware does for for VM.

I should be able to save the state if want to test something

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off-topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Symantec NetBackup with the Hyper-V extensions ([Clicky)](http://www.microsoft.com/isv/symantec/hyperv.aspx)

Comment: thnaks buddy i will try that

Answer (score 0):

Acronis Trueimage has the required features too.